# How to write tsql search function with a variable or unknown amount of parameters?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I'm trying to write a t-sql function that will search a database for certain fields but only if the fields aren't empty.  So in the query below, my c# call will pass these parameters in but if I don't want to pass in one of the parameters or one of them is null, I would like it to still search but only by the fields that aren't null (Basically excluded from the where clause).  Is there an easy way to do this? or will i have to make separate queries for every combination of inputs??

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Search]
(
    @firstname VarChar(50),
    @lastname VarChar(80),
    @userId VarChar(50),
    @vehicle VarChar(50)
)
RETURNS @returntable TABLE
(
    firstname VarChar(50),
    lastname VarChar(80),
    userId VarChar(50),
    vehicle VarChar(50),
    passengers VarChar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT @returntable
    SELECT * FROM Drivers
    Where firstname = @firstname and lastname = @lastname and 
          userid = @userId and vehicle = @vehicle
RETURN
END
```

Comment: why you want to write it as a fucntion ?

Comment: Sure this is pretty common. It is a catch-all query. Here is an excellent article about this topic. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/ BTW, this would be better suited as a stored procedure instead of a table valued function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will allow for ignoring the parameters that are set to NULL.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Search]
(
    @firstname VarChar(50),
    @lastname VarChar(80),
    @userId VarChar(50),
    @vehicle VarChar(50)
)
RETURNS @returntable TABLE
(
    firstname VarChar(50),
    lastname VarChar(80),
    userId VarChar(50),
    vehicle VarChar(50),
    passengers VarChar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT @returntable
    SELECT * FROM Drivers
    Where (@firstname IS NULL OR firstname = @firstname) AND 
          (@lastname IS NULL OR lastname = @lastname) AND  
          (@userId IS NULL OR userid = @userId) AND 
          (@vehicle IS NULL OR vehicle = @vehicle)
RETURN
END
```

Comment: Awesome! I was hoping for something simple like this, thank you for your help!

Comment: This would be better suited if it was converted to an inline table valued function. The way this is written it is unnecessarily slower than it needs to be.

Comment: I'm running into a problem with this method, however, when I try to call it using SqlDataAdapter (c#).  It seems to not like me passing the function null values and causes an exception to be thrown as if the parameter is missing...

Comment: Does naming the parameters when calling the function?

Answer (score 2):

you can skip filters which are `null`

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Search]
(   
    @firstname VarChar(50),
    @lastname VarChar(80),
    @userId VarChar(50),
    @vehicle VarChar(50)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT * FROM Drivers
    Where 
    (@firstname is null or firstname = @firstname)
    and (@lastname is null or lastname = @lastname)
    and (@userId is null or userid = @userId)
    and (@vehicle is null or vehicle = @vehicle)
)
```

Comment: You might take a peek at the article I referenced above. This approach works well but can cause some serious performance problems if you don't handle it correctly.

Comment: @SeanLange, that is an approach i've used in my projects. thanks for a link, i've already begun to read it.